# How to enable Prometheus-based logging in a Cumulocity Cloud microservice

Tags: cumulocity

I've been able to upload a microservice to my Cumulocity tenant. Among other things, the process in my microservice exposes statistics over Prometheus.

We followed the 'Prometheus Monitoring' part of the [documentation](http://www.cumulocity.com/guides/reference/microservice-manifest/) and pointed the manifest file at the URL and port that our process exposes for prometheus.

However, it's unclear how this is exposed in the `Cumulocity API/tooling/UI` - nothing obvious has shown up in the UI, and Prometheus isn't mentioned anywhere else in the documentation.

So, in theory Cumulocity is scraping the stats from the process within our running microservice. How can I see those stats as a Cumulocity user?

Answer (score 2):

Enabling the prometheus extension in a microservice via the microservice manifest only results in exposing metrics via an endpoint (default: /prometheus | /prometheus.json).

You can view the data by running a Prometheus server and configure it to scrape the metrics of your microservice.

AFAIK you cannot directly see these stats within the cumulocity UI.